# How do I "peek" at a running but detached screen?

Tags: linux, ubuntu

I have a script that runs in the background on a detached screen but doesn't write to a log file.  (`screen -dmS somename somescript`)

When I check on the script, I attach to it (`screen -r somename`) then detach when I'm done (`C-a d`).

Instead of attaching then detaching, is it possible to simply "peek" at what's on the screen?
Something similar to `echo "$(screen -r somename)"` that actually works?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `-X` option sends a command to a running screen instance:

```
screen -r somename -X hardcopy
```

the `hardcopy` command writes a screen dump into `hardcopy.N`, where `N` is the index of the active screen.

Comment: Works like a charm!  My only problem is that now I'm having a hard time "resizing" the screen to get enough content on the hardcopy to be useful.  I tried the `resize` command for `-X` but had no luck.  I could only get it to "resize" if I resumed the window and stretched my extended my SSH window.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Not sure, but I don't think you can resize a region bigger than the terminal. I guess when the screen is detached, it uses the size of the last terminal it was attached to as the limit.